# I am trying use vlog inside static lamba giving me error: statement-expressions are not allowed outside funstions nor in template-argument lists

Tags: c++11, lambda, glog

I wrote a global static lambda like the following:

```
 static auto x = [] (const std::string& y){
   VLOG(3) <<" y:" <<y; 
 };
```

it is giving me this error on VLOG statement.:

```
 statement-expressions are not allowed outside functions nor in template-argument lists
```

Comment: Try giving your lambda an explicit return type: `[] (const std::string& y) -> void { ...}`.

Answer (score 1):

This is the result of a decision made to leave room for optimizations. The relevant bug report is [here](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=17082) in an attempt to reopen the discussion, and specifically mentions your type of use case.  Compiling without optimizations should work, though I know that's a lame suggestion. The problem is with the lambda being at global scope, so any solution that brings it into a function should be good.